# popBackStack() works in Fragment but not from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, fragment-backstack

I am simply closing `fragment` and going back to previous one by

```
 getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

And it works, `fragment` is closed. But when I put the same code in the activity method and call it, then nothing happens.

```
 ((FragmentRouter)getActivity()).goBack();
```

And the implementation

```
@Override
public void goBack() {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

How can it be? The code is the same and we are in the same line of event processing.

Comment: Which activity class you use? `class <your activity> extends <what?>`

Comment: put your `Activity` class and `Fragment` class

Comment: post more code...

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

My fault: of course the two calls of getFragmentManager() are not identical, since they include implicit "this" which is Fragment in one case and Activity in another case.

Works by using:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()
```

in Activity